# Folder of Flatfiles as Datasource SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to automatically merge and upload all the .csv files contained in a folder with SSIS. Every month a new file is added and I would like to always have all the files in the folder to be uploaded. I don't want to updated the MULTIFLATFILES data connection every month to include the new file, but for it to be done automatically. Is this even possible? I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You can use a For Each Loop Container in SSIS to loop through all of the files in the folder. Take a look at this [example](http://help.pragmaticworks.com/dtsxchange/scr/FAQ%20-%20How%20to%20loop%20through%20files%20in%20a%20specified%20folder,%20load%20one%20by%20one%20and%20move%20to%20archive%20folder%20using%20SSIS.htm) for the basic structure of this typical SSIS pattern.